# unit test in netbeans using JUnit

Tags: netbeans, junit

I have run a test using JUnit in NetBeans, and I get this test results :

[image]

and this is the output message :

> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Time elapsed: 0,336 sec
>
> ------------- Standard Output --------------- avant tout après tout
>   ------------- ---------------- --------------- Testcase: calculette.calculMethodeTest:    Caused an ERROR Illegal local variable
>   table length 24 in method
>   calculette.Calculette.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 24 in
>   method calculette.Calculette.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V   at
>   calculette.calculMethodeTest.setUpClass(calculMethodeTest.java:24)
>
> Testcase: calculette.calculMethodeTest:   Caused an ERROR null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   calculette.calculMethodeTest.tearDownClass(calculMethodeTest.java:30)
>
> Test calculette.calculMethodeTest FAILED test-report:
>   C:\Users\Aimad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Calculette\nbproject\build-impl.xml:933:
>   Some tests failed; see details above. BUILD FAILED (total time: 12
>   seconds)

what are these errors means ?

this is the test methods :

```
**
     * Test of main method, of class Calculette.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        System.out.println("main");
        String[] args = null;
        Calculette.main(args);
    }

    /**
     * Test of multiplication method, of class Calculette.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMultiplication() {
        System.out.println("multiplication");
        double a = 2.0;
        double b = -5.0;
        Calculette instance = new Calculette();
        double expResult = -10.0;
        double result = instance.multiplication(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    }

    /**
     * Test of division method, of class Calculette.
     */
    @Test (expected = DivisionSurZeroException.class)
    public void testDivision()  {
        System.out.println("division");
        double a = 0.0;
        double b = 0.0;
        Calculette instance = new Calculette();
        double expResult = a/b;
        double result = instance.division(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = 10;
        b = 10;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = 10;
        b = 0;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = 10;
        b = -10;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = 0;
        b = 10;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = 0;
        b = -10;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = -10;
        b = 10;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = -10;
        b = 0;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);

        a = -10;
        b = -10;
        expResult = a/b;
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    }

    /**
     * Test of addition method, of class Calculette.
     */
    @Test
    public void testAddition() {
        System.out.println("addition");
        double a = -10.1;
        double b = -70.0;
        Calculette instance = new Calculette();
        double expResult = a + b;
        double result = instance.addition(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    }

    /**
     * Test of soustraction method, of class Calculette.
     */
    @Test
    public void testSoustraction() {
        System.out.println("soustraction");
        double a = -60.5;
        double b = 5.0;
        Calculette instance = new Calculette();
        double expResult = a - b;
        double result = instance.soustraction(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    }
```

And this is the original methods :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Calculette().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

 @Override
    public double multiplication(double a, double b) {
        return a*b;
    }

    @Override
    public double division(double a, double b)  {
        if(b == 0) throw new DivisionSurZeroException();
        else return a/b;
    }

    @Override
    public double addition(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Override
    public double soustraction(double a, double b) {
        return a-b;
    }
```

Comment: this means nothing without code for the methods

Comment: @AngryDuck the test methods or the original methods ?

Comment: well both to be honest but more so original methods

Comment: stripped down of course to only show relevant code dont go posting hundreds of lines

Comment: @AngryDuck Okey, please see the modifications I've made to my post

Comment: ok having a look now will take me a while tho its a bit of a mess with no comments

Comment: also can i say that for most of your `expResult` dont just do the same calculation on them that your testing for, actually insert the value of the correct answer otherwise your not testing anything at all

Comment: @AngryDuck the 0.0 is generated by the JUnit and I leave it that way.

Comment: can you remove it and see what happens please

Comment: you shouldn't have code unless you know what it does, also i bet you dont know why you have all those `override` tags either right?

Comment: @AngryDuck override as I know it to ovveride an abstract method which is defined in an interface, and the class which imlements this interface should also implement all it's abstract methods and then ovveride them

Comment: fair enough its just i couldnt see that from the code, anyway have you removed the 0.0 at the end of your assert equals

Comment: @AngryDuck When I deleted the 0.0 from the assertEquals methods I got the error when I run  the JUnit test : `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers`

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH haha i know why there all failing

Comment: try using a small decimal number as your delta not 0.0, i think its assuming there identical if you use 0 which they wont be

Comment: @AngryDuck do you lean to replace all 0.0 in my code with 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

While it is a good call that `0.0` is not a very meaningful delta for testing double mathematics (small, positive, non-zero number is what you typically want, take a look here for some [discussion about what the delta is](http://www.coderanch.com/t/94967/Testing/jUnit-assert-delta)), I don't believe that is to blame for the error.  That should just result in unexpectedly failing tests.

This issue seems to come up related changes to the Byte Code Verifier, in Java 7.  I appears that you can fix the issue by passing the argument

```
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

(You can refer to this [NetBeans resource](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqPlatformRuntimeProperties) If you need help on how to set these args)